# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that every community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Mithrandir]
[image: Emrakul]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/flair/80.png))</sub>

[image: Gallifreyan]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them and appreciate the hard work and time they will contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are many members here who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, moderators should be elected by the community, and that's why we'll hold elections once the site graduates.

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Congrats, and our sincere appreciation, to all the new mods! I shall do my level best not to be a PITA.

Comment: Congratulations guys, nice to see a combination of experienced mods and fresh blood.

Comment: Kudos. I'm sure you'll continue to do us proud.

Comment: Every mod team could do with a Time Lord: to clear the site of problems past, present, *and* future ;-)

Answer (score 12):

You guys - well, save Emrakul, who's already a mod elsewhere - have absolutely no idea what you're getting yourselves into. Being a mod on a beta site can be really, really hard, and frustrating, and painful, and lonely. And you're willing to jump into it wholeheartedly. I salute your courage, and wish you all the best of luck.

[<strike>O captain! My captain!</strike>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Captain!_My_Captain!) O moderators! My moderators!<sup>1</sup>

<sup>I mean the Walt Whitman poem, not the use in the film *Dead Poets Society*.</sup>

Comment: Well,  that's encouraging...

Comment: Or it can be really, really easy... and boring... but I'm going to bet Lit won't be one of those sites.

Comment: @Mithrandir congrats and good luck. Just... don't introduce any sandboxes, Ok? :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil :P (I think you meant to say that to Emrak... ;))

Comment: That was a film, dude. This is **Literature**.

Comment: @Valorum It was supposed to be in tribute to the original poem.

Comment: As one of the provisional moderators - and by far the largest contributor to - the first attempt at Literature.SE, I'll echo these sentiments and wish you all better success than I was able to achieve the first time around :)

Answer (score 3):

First off, congrats to you all!

I hope that we and the CMs have wisely chosen the best people in the community to lead Literature SE into the new age of public beta, and hopefully beyond into graduation.

I also hope that you excel in the duty you have been honoured with, and will carry out the duty successfully. It may be a bit of a bumpy ride to start with, but may you have the resilience and courage to overcome these setbacks and leave them in the past.

Also a massive thanks to everyone who voted for someone, without your votes these people could not have been chosen.

Good luck, and have fun!

<sub>(Also, no sandboxes here please Emrakul. You know what happened last time ;) )</sub>

Comment: "*Also a massive thanks to everyone who voted for someone, without your votes these people could not have been chosen.*" - that's absolutely not true. The CMs take meta voting into account when making their selection, but they're in no way obligated to follow it; sometimes they select people who haven't even been mentioned on the meta nominations at all.

Comment: @Randal'Thor well in this case the three top voted were chosen so... tbh I just wrote this as I wanted to thank people and say well done, but this answer has been torn to shreds so I give up. I've already edited once to mention CMs, don't think I'm going to bother editing any more :(